# Adobe Acrobat toggle button - show/hide field

Tags: javascript, acrobat

What I want is a button in Acrobat that would hide a field if it's visible and show it if it's hidden, alternatively.

I know there is a way to do one or the either on MouseUp, but I want to do both using the same button.

This where I got so far:

```
var Strikethrough = this.getField("text_strikethrough");
if(Strikethrough.display = display.hidden){Strikethrough.display = display.visible
} else {Strikethrough.display = display.hidden}
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be working.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
var Strikethrough = this.getField("text_strikethrough");
if(Strikethrough.display == display.hidden){Strikethrough.display = display.visible
} else {Strikethrough.display = display.hidden}
```

I used '==' instead of '=' in the "if condition".

Comment: Thank you.
In the meantime I managed to use a checkbox that was visible but not printing to do this since isBoxChecked(0) was easier for me to work with in this case, but I was hoping there was a simpler way to achieve my goal.

Comment: It looked to me as if you already had all the necessary elements to show/hide the field (“text_strikethrough”) using another field to control the display. The code attached to the MouseUp event of the control button was fine except for the condition that I corrected. Check out the form in http://www.aespen.ca/AEnswers/RHLrR1454835381.pdf; it has the show/hide field (“text_strikethrough”) and a control button (called “ControlButton”). “ControlButton” has the MouseUp event with your code. And it works.

Comment: Yes. It works exactly as it should. That's why I selected your answer.
In my case, however, I put the button over the "text" I wanted to show/hide - which is a bunch of "—" em lines to make up an improvised strikethrough over an existing text that I didn't want to touch because it's an official document.
I think I finally understood the importance of knowing the difference between = and == in java. Thank you, again.

Answer (score 1):

It is correct behavior… the shortcuts "display.hidden" or "display.visible" are honored only when setting, not when getting.

Instead you use the codes for which "display.hidden" or "display.visible" stand. You can get them easily by setting the option for a field, and then use the Console to return the code.

However, for brevity's sake, here are the codes:

```
0: visible
1: hidden
2: noPrint
3: noView
```

When you test for these codes, your script should work.

Comment: I appreciate the explanation and was about to start searching for the way to use those codes when John answered.